# How to know which button was pressed in flask form? (Flask, HTML)

Tags: python, flask

I have used a for loop to populate spotify song links and embed them on a web page. After each song is a button called "like" and "dislike" - here is the html:

```
 {% for (song_name, song_uri, submission_id) in songs: %}
 <br>
 <form action="" method="post">
     <div name="song" value="{{submission_id}}, {{song_name}}"><iframe
     src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/{{song_uri}}" height="80" frameborder="0"
     allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
     <input type="submit" value="Like"></input> 
     <input type="submit" value="Dislike"></input>
 </form> 
 {% endfor %}
```

Let's pretend there are 4 songs listed, with submission_id's of 1, 2, 3, 4, respectively.
I would like to then count whether the user clicked the "like" or "dislike" button for a specific song.

If the user clicks "Like" on song #1 (submission_id = "1"), then I will extract the link of that song and use it in my backend. I'm not sure how to have each button correspond to a request from my flask app so when a user clicks "Like", I know they meant song #1 (submission_id = "1").

So far I've tried this in my flask app:

```
  @app.route('/curator', methods=["GET","POST"])
  def curator():

    songs = load_songs.load_songs()

    if request.method == "POST":
        song_number = request.form['submission_id']
```

This however results in the following error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a 
request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'submission_id'
```

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick - use the like / dislike button to send a request to the api and send the id in the request body, then accept the id to process it. an example request would be something like this:
`GET: songs / like /? id = 1`

After you have created the api method described above, you can access it by clicking on the button in the form of an ajax request, which will allow you to track the number of likes / dislikes without refreshing the page and, in general, do whatever you want

example ajax:

```java
var endpoint = 'songs/likes/?id={{submission_id}}'
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url:endpoint,
        success: function (result){
            console.log("do something if successful, like display the next song") 
})
```

in the end, the mechanism is very simple. You set the id to the buttons, then by clicking on the button, ajax is called which will make a request to the api with the song id, send information to the back about whether the user liked the composition or not, and then, having already received the result via the api on the backend side, somehow process it

Comment: I'm not quite following, do you mind explaining a little further? 

By api do you mean the spotify API? Because I already have the song link stored in my database, I just need to compare the submission_id on the webpage to the one in the database, then I can get the song link with a simple query. 

I'm very new to web dev so all detail appreciated

Comment: Did I understand correctly that your task is to track that the user has pressed the button and, based on this, somehow process it on the backend?

Comment: Yes the goal is to trigger some functions when the user presses the button. I am not sure how to distinguish between whether the user hits the button for song 1 or song 3 for example

Comment: as it seems to me, based on your request, it makes sense to make an api method that will receive the id, you will receive the id on the backend using an ajax request to this api